# Minkowski Theory

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

In Jurgen Neurich, under the section of Minkowski Theory, the following thing is mentioned,

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be an algebraic extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\tau$ denote complex embedding of $K$ in  $\mathbb{C}$. Let $K_{\mathbb{C}}=\prod_{\tau}\mathbb
{C}$, where $\tau$ varies over $n$ complex embeddings and let galois group $G(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ be generated by complex conjugation, $F:z\mapsto \bar{z}$. Now, $F$ acts on $K_{\mathbb{C}}\mapsto K_{\mathbb{C}}$, by conjugating each factor and also by conjugating $\tau$ according to Neurich.

The definition of $K_{\mathbb{C}}$ is little confusing. The way I understood it is, $K_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the direct product of the embedded fields of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Can anyone explain why $F$ acts on $K_{\mathbb{C}}$, by conjugating each factors as well as $\tau$? In other words, why $F(z)=\bar{z}_{\bar{\tau}}$, where $z\in K_{\mathbb{C}}$. Again I am not quite sure about the notation, so I may have not explained it properly.

Comment: Can anyone answer this?

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: Yes thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of action is correct. One might say that there is some abuse of notation but everything is clear once we understand what is going on. I explain it a bit here.
Think of $K_{\mathbb C} $ as direct product of $\mathbb C $s with complex embeddings $\tau $s as labels. It may be a good idea to write it as $$K_{\mathbb C} = \prod _{\tau} \mathbb C_{\tau} $$
When $F$ acts, it acts on the elements as well as the labels. It shuffles the elements in the direct product (and also acts on the elements themselves, by conjugation), via conjugation.
So for example suppose we only have a pair of complex embeddings, say for $\mathbb Q [i] / \mathbb Q $, then $K_{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C \times \mathbb C $. Let $\tau $ and $\bar \tau $ be the natural embedding and conjugate of that.
Here an element of $K_{\mathbb C}$ looks like $(\__{\tau}, \__{\bar \tau}) $. Say we have $(i,0) $, then $F$ acts on this as $F(i,o)=(0,-i) $.

Comment: I have one ques, what does $x\in K_{\mathbb{C}}$ means? Does it mean a tupple where $x_i\in \mathbb{C}_{\tau}$? In the textbook it is described as a $\mathbb{C}$ vector space...But does not actually fully behaves like it?

Comment: Yes, it's a tuple and K_C is a complex vector space.

Comment: Under addition it is closed. Why under scaler(complex) multiplication it is closed?

Comment: Also, can you help me understand the structure $K_{\mathbb{R}}$? In text it is described there is a map $j:K\mapsto K_{\mathbb{R}}$, can you help me understand what this map is doing? @Mathemather